# "An internal error has occurred while evaluating method Activator.CreateInstance()"

Tags: c#, .net

I'm loading types from files found in two directories and creating an instance of each type using `System.Activator`.  I've done this a number of times without any issue, which makes me think I'm about to learn something.

The files in the first directory are loaded without issue.  At the first file in the next directory, it gets to the point of calling `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` and continues on without exception, but the returned instance can't be evaluated ("*Could not evaluate expression*").  Trying to execute the same statement in the QuickWatch window produces the above error as a value with type "object", not an exception.

What I've tried:

- Reference the assembly that contains the type in question and specifically create an instance using `new` and the empty constructor, even from the same point that this error is about to occur. **(success)**
- Using `Activator` on this type at other points in the call stack. **(failure)**
- The type in question implements an interface, but does not subclass any other classes.
- The assembly is in the AppDomain (obviously, after referencing it specifically).
- Moving the implementing assembly to a different location. **(failure)**

I'm at the point that I don't even know *what* to check, I've never seen this before.

This is Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5.  I can't find any references to this error in the context of `Activator.CreateInstance`.  The only single instance I can find of this error had no resolution.  I don't expect the information I've provided to lead to a resolution, but if I can at least find out possible causes, I can research my own solutions.

Comment: This is the debugger itself failing, not your code.  Lord knows how you did that, there are no clues in your question.  You need to plow ahead, this kind of failure does tend to correct itself.

Comment: @HansPassant, please post that as an answer so I can accept it.  Everything having to do with the created instance in question couldn't be evaluated by the debugger until a value was pulled from a property.  But it didn't bother the execution at all, so you seem to be right.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on Fusion Logging and check out what fusion is doing and make sure it is able to find + load the assembly.

[Scott Hanselman - Back to Basics: Using Fusion Log Viewer to Debug Obscure Loader Errors](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)

At the time you load it there could be a plethora of issues.

Some I have come across:

- Another version (possibly previous) of the given assembly has been loaded with this type missing.
- This assembly fails to load due to another incompatible version of its dependencies being loaded.